# How to move activity from one display to another

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Android started to support Multi-display from Android 8.0, The document described as below:

> If an activity supports multi-window mode and is running on a device with multiple displays, users can move the activity from one display to another.
> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0#mds

I've tried to start an activity withe the flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT", and "setLaunchDisplayId" with secondary display. The activity I started is shown on the secondary display, but how can I move the activity from the secondary display to my phone?

Comment: Any solutions so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, I don't have an answer for you but I've come across some good reading material for multiple display.

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi_display

This link here indicates that as of Android 10 (API 29) that users can move activities on a device that is running multiple displays.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/foldables#multi-display